# Ether password recovery

Tags: ether, password

I've been trying for weeks to recover password for my ETH from a year ago. No luck.
How does this python recover thing work? Is it something you have to download? Or where do you type things?
Can anyone step-by-step explain this, I'm a complete newbie when it comes to this.

Much appreciated.

Peter

Comment: Dave @ https://walletrecoveryservices.com/ is super helpful if you have an idea of what you password may be. He has amazing reviews. Check out his site for more details on what he can and cannot recover.